# Hard drive clicking on Z500 (13.10)

Tags: hard-drive, lenovo, 13.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop, which is a Lenovo Z500. Everything works nicely so far, but occasionally there is some hard drive clicking.

I tried using the command:

```
 hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda
```

With no avail, though.

Can anyone help? This laptop has been problematic with a lot of Linux distributions, and it always had that same clicking problem. If there is some more info that I can provide, just tell me, and I'll edit the post.

The hard drive is a Seagate ST500LT012-9WS142.

**Edit #1**: As this question has been marked as a possible duplicate, I should add more info. I've read the posts that have been suggested, and I came across using the `hdparm` command, which, as I said, does not work for me.

As someone else suggested, the file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-ap` should be edited. I have not tried that on Ubuntu 13.10, and I will attempt it, but as far as I remember, the `hdparm` command is being issued in that script as well.

I will also attempt to edit `/etc/hdparm.conf`, and will come back with the results.

I'd also like to add that I did try these two methods on other distros, and they didn't give the wanted result. :/ But, yes, I understand that those are other distros and that these methods might work on Ubuntu, so I'll try.

**Edit #2**: Editing `/etc/hdparm.conf` did not bring any satisfactory results. The clicking is still occurring.

The code used was:

```
/dev/sda {
    apm = 254
    apm_battery = 254
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I would not classify it as a duplicate, as that post is about Ubuntu 11.10. That system probably wouldn't work on my laptop. But a stronger reason for my belief is the fact that I ran a 12.04-based distro on my laptop without the clicking. So, the problem is related to the newer kernel/software, I think.

Comment: Maybe the default configuration by the distribution is different nowadays. Could you try ImaginaryRobot's links and try to override it?

Comment: Edited /etc/hdparm.conf. Will now restart and confirm whether the problem persists or not.
Thanks for all the answers! :)

Comment: Well, it didn't work. I'm terribly sorry for replying after so long, but I've been really busy with college.

Comment: If anyone is wondering about this - Ubuntu 14.04 fixed the issue for me.  It's working without problems. Let me know if I need to post this as an answer, as I'm not too familiar with Stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with Seagate for a possible firmware update. Similar models http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Laptop-HDD-Laptop-SSHD-Momentus/ST9500420ASG-Momentus-7200-4-clicking-noise/m-p/30598/highlight/true#M1777 have needed such.

Comment: No firmware update available. :/
Thanks a lot for your suggestion! It was a really good idea that didn't occur to me. :)